# Java Client-Server GUI Swing App with Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, client-server

I am trying to implement multithreading into my Client-Server GUI app based on Swing.

I followed this tutorial to make the GUI portion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3i459_arng

And right now I'm using this tutorial to add the multithreading: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIzoesrHHQo

So far I've managed to get the multithreading done. I can run the ChatClient multiple times, and I can request the server to send the text from txt files to a specific client. However, since I added the multithreading, my server no longer prints "Client found" or any of the requests sent from the clients. It just says "Waiting for Clients..." and that's it.

If someone knows what I'm doing wrong or can direct me to a resource where I can figure it out, I'd appreciate it.

Edit: I remember that in my previous code before attempting multithreading, I had

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
});
myThread.start();
```

In my ChatServer code. So I added that back in. That has allowed my server to recognize when the client chat windows are open, it shows "Client found." in its chat window.

Something I didn't notice until now, was that before I would run the ChatServer file, then run the ChatClient file, enter a command in the client chat and receive the expected response, then run the ChatClient file again, enter another command, get a response, etc. It appears to be working.

However, when I run the ChatServer file, then run the ChatClient file multiple times without entering a command first, a command that I enter in the first client chat window will only show the response in the last client chat window. And after that, only the last client chat window I opened can send commands and receive responses. Any thoughts on what caused this, and how I can resolve it?

ChatClient.java file

```
package clientserver2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ChatClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ChatClient() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextAreaChat = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextAreaMessage = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButtonSend = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Client");
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout(10, 10));

        jTextAreaChat.setColumns(20);
        jTextAreaChat.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextAreaChat);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout(10, 10));

        jTextAreaMessage.setColumns(20);
        jTextAreaMessage.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextAreaMessage);

        jPanel1.add(jScrollPane2, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jButtonSend.setText("Send");
        jButtonSend.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonSendActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButtonSend, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setBounds(0, 0, 407, 342);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButtonSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String message = jTextAreaMessage.getText();
        writer.println(message);
        writer.flush();

        jTextAreaChat.append("Client: " + message + "\n");
        jTextAreaMessage.setText("");
    }                                           

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 4789);
            scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            
            Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){                
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    
                        jTextAreaChat.append("Welcome! Please enter a command." + "\n");
                        jTextAreaChat.append("Enter products to view list of products." + "\n");
                        jTextAreaChat.append("Enter customers to view list of customers." + "\n");
                
                    while(true){
                        String message = scanner.nextLine();
                        jTextAreaChat.append(message + "\n");
                    }
                }
            });
            myThread.start();
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        
    }                                 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ChatClient().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonSend;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextAreaChat;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextAreaMessage;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    private Socket socket;
    private Scanner scanner;
    private PrintWriter writer;
}
```

ChatServer.java file

```
package clientserver2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ChatServer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ChatServer() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextAreaChat = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextAreaMessage = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButtonSend = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Server");
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout(10, 10));

        jTextAreaChat.setColumns(20);
        jTextAreaChat.setRows(5);
        jTextAreaChat.setText("\n");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextAreaChat);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout(10, 10));

        jTextAreaMessage.setColumns(20);
        jTextAreaMessage.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextAreaMessage);

        jPanel1.add(jScrollPane2, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jButtonSend.setText("Send");
        jButtonSend.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonSendActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButtonSend, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setBounds(0, 0, 407, 342);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButtonSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String message = jTextAreaMessage.getText();
        writer.println(message);
        jTextAreaChat.append("Server: " + message + "\n");
        jTextAreaMessage.setText("");     
    }                                           

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  

        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4789);
            clients = new ArrayList<>();
            pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

            Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while (true) {

                        try {
                            jTextAreaChat.append("Waiting for Client..." + "\n");
                            socket = serverSocket.accept();
                            jTextAreaChat.append("Client found." + "\n");
                            ClientHandler clientThread = new ClientHandler(socket);
                            clients.add(clientThread);
                            pool.execute(clientThread);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
            myThread.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }                                 

             
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ChatServer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        //private final Socket socket;        
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            //this.socket = clientSocket;
            scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {                      
            while (true) {
                String message = scanner.nextLine();
                jTextAreaChat.append("Client: " + message + "\n");

                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("products")) {
                    try {
                        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\jades\\Desktop\\Java\\ClientServer2\\src\\clientserver2\\Products.txt");
                        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
                        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                            writer.println(sc.nextLine());
                            writer.flush();
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("customers")) {
                    try {
                        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\jades\\Desktop\\Java\\ClientServer2\\src\\clientserver2\\Customers.txt");
                        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
                        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                            writer.println(sc.nextLine());
                            writer.flush();
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
               
        }       
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonSend;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextAreaChat;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextAreaMessage;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private Scanner scanner;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private static ArrayList<ClientHandler> clients;
    private static ExecutorService pool;
}
```

Comment: I added a tag and mentions of Swing as your choice of GUI framework. In the Java ecosystem we have a choice of various GUI frameworks including Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Vaadin, and others. So always be clear when posting on Java GUIs.

Comment: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)